# Enviar respuesta de un excel a un Formulario de Google por python

Tags: python, google-api, google-forms

Estoy tratando de automatizar un proceso, el cual se estaban llenando formularios antiguos por medio de excel y hay mas de 1000 archivos con mas de 1000 registro. Ahora se actualizó todo para usarlo con google form. Mi idea es cargar un archivo y me envie los datos al formulario creado, el nombre de cada columna tiene igual nombre al de las preguntas

este es el código que tengo en el momento, soy nuevo con la api de google

**google_forms.py**

```
import os
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


def cargar_credenciales(credentials_file):
    try:
        # Carga las credenciales desde el archivo JSON
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            credentials_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms']
        )
        return credentials
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al cargar las credenciales: {e}")
    return None

def iniciar_servicio_de_formularios(credentials):
    try:
        # Crea una instancia de la API de Google Forms
        forms_service = build('forms', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
        return forms_service
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al iniciar el servicio de Google Forms: {e}")
        return None

def enviar_respuesta_a_formulario(forms_service, form_id, respuesta):
    try:
        # Intenta enviar la respuesta al formulario
        response = forms_service.forms().responses().create(
            formId=form_id, body={'answers': respuesta}
        ).execute()
        print(f'Respuesta enviada con éxito: {response}')
    except HttpError as e:
        # Captura y muestra el error
        print(f'Error al enviar la respuesta: {e}')
```

**excel_loader.py**

```
import pandas as pd

def cargar_datos_desde_excel(file_path):
    try:
        # Utiliza pandas para cargar datos desde Excel o CSV
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl', skiprows=1)  # o pd.read_csv(file_path) para archivos CSV
        # Convierte el DataFrame a una lista de diccionarios
        datos = df.to_dict(orient='records')
        return datos
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al cargar datos desde el archivo: {e}")
        return []
```

**main.py**

```
from google_forms import iniciar_servicio_de_formularios, enviar_respuesta_a_formulario, cargar_credenciales
from excel_loader import cargar_datos_desde_excel

if __name__ == "__main__":
    credentials_file = 'Aqui va el enlace de credenciales'


    # Cargar credenciales
    credentials = cargar_credenciales(credentials_file)

    if credentials:
        # ID del formulario de Google
        form_id = 'el id del formulario'

         # Iniciar el servicio de Google Forms
        forms_service = iniciar_servicio_de_formularios(credentials)

        if forms_service:
            # Cargar datos desde Excel o CSV
            datos = cargar_datos_desde_excel('datos.xlsx')
            
            # Preparar respuestas para enviar en lote
            respuestas_en_lote = []
            for respuesta in datos:
                respuestas_en_lote.append({'answers': respuesta})

            # Enviar todas las respuestas en lote
            try:
                response = forms_service.forms().responses().create(
                    formId=form_id, body={'responses': datos}
                ).execute()
                print(f'Respuestas enviadas con éxito: {response}')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error al enviar las respuestas: {e}")
```

y este es el error que me sale

```
Error al enviar las respuestas: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'batchCreate'
```

según lo que habia averiguado para enviar por lote es **batchCreate** pero de todas maneras al usar **create** tampoco permite y creo que el error está después de que lee el archivo excel